# Moving things in terminal based on their name

Tags: file, bash, parsing, terminal, directory

Edit: I think this has been answered successfully, but I can't check 'til later.  I've reformatted it as suggested though.

**The question**: I have a series of files, each with a name of the form XXXXNAME, where XXXX is some number.  I want to move them all to separate folders called XXXX and have them called NAME.  I can do this manually, but I was hoping that by naming them XXXXNAME there'd be some way I could tell Terminal (I think that's the right name, but not really sure) to move them there.  Something like

mv *NAME */NAME

but where it takes whatever * was in the first case and regurgitates it to the path.

This is on some form of Linux, with a bash shell.

In the real life case, the files are 0000GNUmakefile, with sequential numbering.  I'm having to make lots of similar-but-slightly-altered versions of a program to compile and run on a cluster as part of my research.  It would probably have been quicker to write a program to edit all the files and put in the right place in the first place, but I didn't.

This is probably extremely simple, and I should be able to find an answer myself, if I knew the right words.  Thing is, I have no formal training in programming, so I don't know what to call things to search for them.  So hopefully this will result in me getting an answer, and maybe knowing how to find out the answer for similar things myself next time.  With the basic programming I've picked up, I'm sure I could write a program to do this for me, but I'm hoping there's a simple way to do it just using functionality already in Terminal.  I probably shouldn't be allowed to play with these things.

Thanks for any help!  I can actually program in C and Python a fair amount, but that's through trial and error largely, and I still don't know what I can do and can't do in Terminal.

Comment: move the first paragraph to the very end. Start off with the question

Comment: Also, I think that you'll still need to write some shell script to do it.

Comment: Also, define your problem better.  What is "NAME" and "XXXX"?  How is the boundary between them determined programatically?  Is "XXXX" supposed to be exactly 4 of any character?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SO many ways to achieve this.

I find that the old standbys `sed` and `awk` are often the most powerful.

```
ls | sed -rne 's:^([0-9]{4})(NAME)$:mv -iv & \1/\2:p'
```

If you're satisfied that the commands look right, pipe the command line through a shell:

```
ls | sed -rne 's:^([0-9]{4})(NAME)$:mv -iv & \1/\2:p' | sh
```

I put NAME in brackets and used `\2` so that if it varies more than your example indicates, you can come up with a regular expression to handle your filenames better.

To do the same thing in `gawk` (GNU awk, the variant found in most GNU/Linux distros):

```
ls | gawk '/^[0-9]{4}NAME$/ {printf("mv -iv %s %s/%s\n", $1, substr($0,0,4), substr($0,5))}'
```

As with the first sample, this produces commands which, if they make sense to you, can be piped through a shell by appending `| sh` to the end of the line.

Note that with all these `mv` commands, I've added the `-i` and `-v` options.  This is for your protection.  Read the man page for `mv` (by typing `man mv` in your Linux terminal) to see if you should be comfortable leaving them out.

Also, I'm assuming with these lines that all your directories already exist.  You didn't mention if they do.  If they don't, here's a one-liner to create the directories.

```
ls | sed -rne 's:^([0-9]{4})(NAME)$:mkdir -p \1:p' | sort -u
```

As with the others, append `| sh` to run the commands.

I should mention that it is generally recommended to use constructs like `for` (in Tim's answer) or `find` instead of parsing the output of `ls`.  That said, when your filename format is as simple as `/[0-9]{4}word/`, I find the quick `sed` one-liner to be the way to go.

Lastly, if by `NAME` you actually mean "any string of characters" rather than the literal string "NAME", then in all my examples above, replace `NAME` with `.*`.

Comment: @l0b0 - You will note that I *did* mention that in my answer.  However, the article you linked to on Greg's wiki talks about using `ls` in situations [where filename format is problematic](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29).  In this case, the format described is very simple, and `ls` won't have a problem with it.  Further, I made it very clear that the commands generated should be sanity-checked before being executed.  I really don't think this deserves a downvote.

Answer (score 1):

The following script will do this for you.  Copy the script into a file on the remote machine (we'll call it sortfiles.sh).

```
#!/bin/bash

# Get all files in current directory having names XXXXsomename, where X is an integer
files=$(find . -name '[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*')

# Build a list of the XXXX patterns found in the list of files
dirs=
for name in ${files}; do
  dirs="${dirs} $(echo ${name} | cut -c 3-6)"
done

# Remove redundant entries from the list of XXXX patterns
dirs=$(echo ${dirs} | uniq)

# Create any XXXX directories that are not already present
for name in ${dirs}; do
  if [[ ! -d ${name} ]]; then
    mkdir ${name}
  fi
done

# Move each of the XXXXsomename files to the appropriate directory
for name in ${files}; do
  mv ${name} $(echo ${name} | cut -c 3-6)
done

# Return from script with normal status
exit 0
```

From the command line, do `chmod +x sortfiles.sh`

Execute the script with `./sortfiles.sh`

Comment: Note that this solution assumes the numeric filename prefix is exactly 4 digits.

Comment: This won't work if there are spaces in the filenames or dirnames.  The root problem is with the initial `find` command.  Any spaces in the file names will be treated as a separate file.  It's also expensive to fire up echo and cut for simple string operations that bash provides out of the box.

Answer (score 1):

Just open the Terminal application, `cd` into the directory that contains the files you want moved/renamed, and copy and paste these commands into the command line.

```
for file in [0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]*; do
  dirName="${file%%*([^0-9])}"
  mkdir -p "$dirName"
  mv "$file" "$dirName/${file##*([0-9])}"
done
```

This assumes all the files that you want to rename and move are in the same directory.  The file globbing also assumes that there are at least four digits at the start of the filename.  If there are more than four numbers, it will still be caught, but not if there are less than four.  If there are less than four, take off the appropriate number of `[0-9]`s from the first line.

It does not handle the case where "NAME" (i.e. the name of the new file you want) starts with a number.

See [this site](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html) for more information about string manipulation in bash.

Comment: This spits out errors if `$dirName` already exists, and doesn't handle cases where NAME is actually a string that starts with a digit.  I.e. `00019999` should be moved to `0001/9999`.

Comment: See my changes.  Errors won't affect output.  Good point about the numbers, I meant to mention that earlier.

Comment: You can also eliminate the errors with `mkdir -p "$dirName"`, as ghoti showed.